# Report toolbar not rendering correctly in Report Manager. How to fix?

Tags: reporting-services, https, ssrs-2008

Using SQL Server Reporting Services 2008 and just noticed that the report toolbar is not rendering correctly when viewing any reports through the Report Manager application.  I am running everything on a Windows 2008 Server without IIS (I'm using http.sys) and all traffic is configured for SSL.

Noticed that I'm getting the following error when the report is displayed:

> **/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=StyleSheet&Version=2007.100.5512.00
>   500 (Internal Server Error)**

Upon further inspection I found out that requesting this .axd file was throwing a **401 (unauthorized)** exception.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: is there any error message in report server log files?

Comment: Try to view the report from SSRS report manager (with credentials you supplied when accesing report viewer web control). If you cant see the report through report manager, verify the account permissions